# Entity Framework Code First: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: value

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I found this strange problem with EF and code annotations, on some entities, the save changes throws this exception.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the **DisplayAttribute** i had on one of my properties of the model, the **Name** property, for some reason, can't be assigned to an empty string, the solution was to use the **DisplayNameAttribute**, which it does support empty strings.